# Jenkinsfile java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method <printpn()> on null object

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have this Jenkinsfile below that I am trying to run but somehow it is throwing `"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method printpn() on null object"` error. Can somebody check what am I missing?

```
[jimmy@localhost]$ cat Jenkinsfile
#!groovy

pipeline {
        agent any

        stages {
                stage('Load Groovy') {
                        steps {
                                script {
                                        def func1 = load('prop.groovy')
                                        func1.printpn()
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
[jimmy@localhost]$ cat prop.groovy
def printpn() {
        sh """#!/usr/bin/env bash

                echo "Coming from groovy function."
        """
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you forgot to write "return this" in your prop.groovy file. Just add "`return this`" in the end like this

```
def printpn() {
        sh """#!/usr/bin/env bash

                echo "Coming from groovy function."
        """
}
return this
```